# Tkinter Scrollabe Window with Zoom/Mouse Scroll and Arrows

Tags: image, tkinter, navigation, scrollbar

i need your help so much, i'm trying to make a window that display a image, but that image is HUGE, and i need that the window be scrollabe, and i want to navigate using the scrollwheel and the keyboard arrows. That i know that's possible, but i just need some help with the code. The biggest problem that i couldn't in anywhere, is the zoom in and zoom out in that image window navigation.

If you can help me I would appreciate it very much. I'm using Tkinter, and the windows as Classes.

> ```
> from tkscrolledframe import ScrolledFrame
> sf = ScrolledFrame(self, width=6800, height=2180, bg="#273852")
>     sf.pack(side="top", expand=1, fill="both")
>     sf.bind_arrow_keys(self)
>     sf.bind_scroll_wheel(self)
>     inner_frame = sf.display_widget(tk.Frame)
>     load = Image.open('overview.jpg')
>     render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
>     img = tk.Label(inner_frame, image=render, bg="#273852", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
>     img.image = render
>     img.grid()
> ```

Ps.: That's the code i'm using, but the arrows and scrollwheel are not working

Comment: Show us a Minimal Working Example; what you done so far that is stripped down to just the issue that you're having difficulty with, then we can help you better.  It also give us something to work with.

Comment: For scrolling, you can bind the arrow keys to a callback and use `canvas.xview_scroll()` and `canvas.yview_scroll()` to move canvas view region.  For zooming, you need to resize the original image (using `Image.resize()` of `Pillow` module) and update the canvas image with the resized image.

Comment: @DavidCollins, i've edited the post, have a look

Comment: @acw1668, i've edited the post, that's the code, but the arrows and scrollwheel are not working. Your idea with the resize is amazing, i will try it. Thank you very much

Comment: Try `sf.bind_arrow_keys(root)` and `sf.bind_scroll_wheel(root)` if `root` is the main window.

Comment: @acw1668 when i try it, the system returns:

> 
  File "C:/SafePlatform.py", line 154, in __init__ sf.bind_arrow_keys(PlatformOverview)

  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\tkscrolledframe\widget.py", line 154, in bind_arrow_keys lambda event: self._canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units"))

  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1251, in bind return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_bind'

Comment: It means that `PlatformOverview` is not the root window and it is a string.

Comment: @acw1668 when i put the root window the same error shows up

Comment: Then try `sf.bind_arrow_keys(img)` and `sf.bind_scroll_wheel(img)`.  You need to move the two statements after `img` is created.  And add `img.focus_set()` after the two statements.

Comment: If all you're displaying is an image, you might want to consider using a canvas rather than a scrolled frame. The canvas will be a bit easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you used `tkscrolledframe`, below is an example that works in my Windows running Python 3:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkscrolledframe import ScrolledFrame
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x600+100+100')

sf = ScrolledFrame(root)
sf.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

img = Image.open('images/big.png')
tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

imgbox = sf.display_widget(tk.Label, image=tkimg)
# make imgbox get focus when mouse clicked on it
imgbox.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: imgbox.focus_set())

sf.bind_arrow_keys(imgbox)
sf.bind_scroll_wheel(imgbox)

# make imgbox get focus in order to receive key events
imgbox.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

In case you want more control and do not use `tkscrolledframe`, below is another example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x600+400+300')

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
hsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hsb.set, yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='images/big.png')
bgimg = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor=tk.NW)
canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, img.width(), img.height()))

def scroll_horizontal(dx):
  canvas.xview_scroll(dx, 'units')

def scroll_vertical(dy):
  canvas.yview_scroll(dy, 'units')

canvas.bind('<MouseWheel>', lambda e: scroll_vertical(-e.delta//120))
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: canvas.focus_set())

canvas.bind('<Up>', lambda e: scroll_vertical(-1))
canvas.bind('<Down>', lambda e: scroll_vertical(+1))
canvas.bind('<Left>', lambda e: scroll_horizontal(-1))
canvas.bind('<Right>', lambda e: scroll_horizontal(+1))

# if using bind_all, no need to call canvas.focus_set()
canvas.focus_set() # canvas must be focused to receive keyboard events

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But when i try this code in my program, it shows a blank window, not my image.

Comment: If you put the code inside a function, then you need to save a reference of the `PhotoImage` like in your posted code.

Comment: Like how? I've putted in a class window

Comment: For the `tkscrolledframe` example, add `imgbox.image = tkimg`.